# What does this Indexer access definition mean?

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone translate into **human** language this sentence from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers#remarks):

> The type of an indexer and the type of its parameters must be at least as accessible as the indexer itself

- So if the **"type of an indexer"** is an **int** or a **float**, for example, then how can an **int** or a **float** be accessible or not? What is the difference between **"type of an indexer"** and **"the indexer itself"**
- So **"parameters"** are those values inside square brackets? Then what are the **formal parameters**?
- And again how can **"type of its parameters"** be accessible or not?
- And then the meaning of the whole sentence, please.

Comment: What if you have an indexer implemented in your own class `MyClass`? It´s surely possible that this class is internal for instance.

Comment: ... see [Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers).

Comment: If your indexer was of type `MyFoo` then that structure needs to be as accessible (i.e. public/internal/etc) as the class it is used in.

Comment: You can't have a `public` method that requires the use of a `private` or `internal` parameter or that returns similar. This is the same deal with indexers, re-written in indexer language. `int` and `float` are both `public` types so can be used anywhere.

Comment: It referring the access {public, private,or nothing} of the indexer and parameter.  So if the indexer is private the parameter can be either private or public.  If the indexer is public then the parameter must be public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply said, you can't make Indexer, Properties or Methods contain types that won't be accessible when using certain access modifier.

Public makes these things visible in other libraries and it won't make sense to expose Indexer which returns or takes type that is `internal`, because it would be unsuable in the other libraries (since you can't use these type).
Same goes if you make the indexer `internal`, you can't make it return or take type that is `private`, because once again it will be unusable in other classes in your library.

But you should know that the accesibility of your indexer depends on enclosing type.

Consider this example:

```
public class Bar { }
public class Foo { }
public class IndexerClass
{
    public Bar this[Foo param]
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

Everything is `public` and should be visible in other libraries, you can't make `Bar` or `Foo` `internal`, because they won't be visible for other libraries. The complier won't allow you to compile this.
If you wanted to make `Bar` or `Foo` `internal` you have to make your indexer less accesible, so you can either make the indexer itself `internal`, or make the class `IndexerClass` `internal`.

```
internal class Foo { }
internal class IndexerClass
{
    public Bar this[Foo param]
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also keep `IndexerClass` to be `public`, if you enclose it in `internal` class. https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfMA7YBTATighhABAAIBM+AwvgN4CwAUPg/qhtnkaQEI6ZX4C+dRkzRZcBEvgBiAe2m8B9RoQDM7fAEkUMdAA8sZCDgDORwYxqKhDFfi49gACzBGA2jLkAHbjgC2AXTMrKkCgxgBzdGBeQgB2fBQAVwgIAG5+EKEFTLo+IA===

Answer (score 1):

An indexer consist of two different types: the type of the index passed in square-brackets and the type of the element that is related to that index. You seem to assume the index is allways an `int`. That´s in no way restricted, it can be of any arbitrary type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ThirdClass this[IndexClass i] { get { ... }; set { ... } }
}
```

This assumes both `ThirdClass` and `IndexClass` are accessable. For example if `IndexClass` were an `internal` class, the abobe code surely won´t compile, because the property (the indexer in our case) is `public`.

This isn´t special to indexers at all. Imagine any usual method:

```
public ThirdClass(IndexClass i)
{
    ...
}
```

Here the same access-rules apply: both `ThirdClass` and `IndexClass` must have **at least the same accessability** (or higher accessability) as the member that exposes those types.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, so it depends on the access level of the indexer? Not the enclosing class? So if this **IndexClass** is internal then the **indexer** should also be internal?

Comment: @PetroKoval It must not be "more" accessable,but it can be "less" (e.g. `private`).

Answer (score 0):

What the documentation is referring to is [Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers).

What this is telling you is that the two types you use, the one returned by the indexer and the one used as a parameter for the index need to have the same level of accessibility as the indexer itself.

Consider this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public IndexerResult this[int index]    // Indexer declaration  
    {  
        // get and set accessors  
    }  
}

internal class IndexerResult
{
   //Some code
}
```

And then you try this:

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
var value = obj[0];
```

If you try to compile, you will get an error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: indexer return type 'IndexerResult' is less accessible than indexer 'SomeClass.this[int]'

The reason is obvious and explained on the message. You can't have a `public` indexer exposing an `internal` class (`IndexerResult`).

The same holds true for parameter `index`. Consider what happens if we flip the types:

```
public int this[IndexerResult index]    // Indexer declaration  
{ 
    // get and set accessors  
}
```

This time around, you are attempting to use a type that is less accessible than the method. How can I create an instance of `IndexerResult` to pass to the indexer if the type is internal?

Now here is the kicker. Consider what happens when you use an interface instead:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public IIndexerResult this[int index]    
    {
        get { return new IndexerResult(); } //This is perfectly fine!
    }
}

internal class IndexerResult : IIndexerResult
{
    //Some code
}

public interface IIndexerResult
{

}
```

This will compile without issue and you will be able to use `internal` class `IndexerResult` externally. This is because the details of the implementation are now hidden behind the interface so you have no knowledge of the actual object. Nothing is "exposed" except for what you choose to expose, which is represented by the interface.